# Replacement for CD4017 / IC sequencers

Tags: led, 555, cd4017

I'm building this circuit from the image below, which is an LED sequencer.
My problem is that where I am now I don't have a CD4017 to do the sequential, but I really need to make this circuit to deliver to the customer.
Is there an equivalent circuit using another IC that has the same clock performance, or some other circuit with simple components that has the same functionality?

Note: I would even buy online, but the urgency is great for delivery.

[image]

Comment: If you can’t get a 4017, what can you get? I could suggest a mega328, but that might be more expensive and harder to get. Currently your question is way too broad.

Comment: Gabriel, I'm not sure if you're aware but there's an "accept" button on each of the answers to this question and all your others. You haven't accepted any despite some of them seeming to have answered your question. Can you address this so the system doesn't keep resurrecting your questions to have them answered. It's also a way of giving some recognition to the authors for their trouble. You can also upvote the accepted answer and any other useful answers. There's more in the [Tour] if you haven't taken it already.

Comment: The 4022 is similar to the 4017, but with 8 outputs instead of 10.

Comment: i have an atmega328p i will do with it, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thank you to everyone here for your co-participation.
I'll follow the tip of you guys who are going to use an atmega328p, as I already have 01 in my hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just for a Led effect, why not to use a transistor ring counter. With a little trick you can move backward also.

[image]

Comment: thank you, i will make one with arduino as suggested here

Answer (score 1):

Microcontroller with enough I/Os can do that.

If you want something more elegant and don't feel like writing code, you could program a Silego Greenpak to do this. The resulting circuit would be *really* tiny, and you could eliminate those diodes.

Comment: thank you, i will make one with arduino as suggested here

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the internal circuit of the CD4017 you can get a good idea of how to make one using other CMOS chips - if you have them. You can also see why it's a good idea to use the CD4017.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: Intersil.*

The obvious thing to do is use a micro-controller with at least six IO pins. If you have an Arduino or similar to hand that would be your best bet.

Comment: thank you, i will make one with arduino as suggested here